# How do I simplify $\frac{bH}{a\sqrt{a^2+H^2}}$ to $\frac{b}{a\sqrt{a^2H^{-2}+1}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I have trouble following the algebraic simplification between step 2 and 3.

> How do I simplify $\frac{bH}{a\sqrt{a^2+H^2}}$ to $\frac{b}{a\sqrt{a^2H^{-2}+1}}$?

Comment: Is this from a nonstandard analysis text?

Comment: @BarryCipra yes. https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go
$$\frac{bH}{a\sqrt{a^2+H^2}}$$
$$=\frac{bH}{a\sqrt{(H^2)(\frac{a^2}{H^2}+1)}}$$
$$=\frac{bH}{aH\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{H^2}+1}}$$
$$=\frac{b}{a\sqrt{a^2H^{-2}+1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{bH}{a\sqrt{a^2+H^2}} \cdot \frac{1/H}{1/H} = \frac{b}{a\sqrt{a^2H^{-2}+1}}$$